# Setting up AWS API Gateway for proxy integration

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway

I have created a Lambda with the following signature

```
    public APIGatewayProxyResponse FunctionHandler(APIGatewayProxyRequest request, ILambdaContext context)
    {
        APIGatewayProxyResponse resp = new APIGatewayProxyResponse();
        var log = context.Logger;
        log.Log($"request = {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request, Formatting.Indented)}");
        log.Log($"context = {JsonConvert.SerializeObject(context, Formatting.Indented)}");

        return resp;
   }
```

I have defined two methods on an API Gateway.

Method #1 - is set as a Lambda, it works but the request is null when invoked.

Method #2 - is set with "Use Lambda Proxy integration" checked - this fails with a response of..

```
{
"message": "Internal server error"
}
```

The logs contain no details of any errors so I am not sure how I can track down the cause of the error. On the basis that "Method #1" work then I am assuming there is an issue somewhere with the APIGatewayProxyRequest but cannot check this.

Any ideas?

Comment: Nothing in either the Lambda or the API Gateway log?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
APIGatewayProxyResponse resp = new APIGatewayProxyResponse();
```

Create a response with StatusCode = 0

Can you change it to 200 and see if It works?

Comment: Yep - that was the issue. Thanks